# How Matrix.preRotate() | Matrix.setRotate() | Matrix.postRotate() transformation works in Android

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es

As far Matrix.preTranslate(float dx, float dy) works like this(In mathematical form) :

```
[MSCALE_X MSKEW_X MTRANS_X]   [1 0 MTRANS_X]
[MSKEW_Y MSCALE_Y MTRANS_Y] * [0 1 MTRANS_Y] 
[MPERSP_0 MPERSP_1 MPERSP_2]  [0 0 1]
```

and Matrix.preScale(float sx, float sy) works like this(In mathematical form) :

```
[MSCALE_X MSKEW_X MTRANS_X]   [MSCALE_X 0 0]
[MSKEW_Y MSCALE_Y MTRANS_Y] * [0 MSCALE_Y 0] 
[MPERSP_0 MPERSP_1 MPERSP_2]  [0 0 1]
```

and Matrix.preSkew(float kx, float ky) works line this :

```
[MSCALE_X MSKEW_X MTRANS_X]   [1 MSKEW_X 0]
[MSKEW_Y MSCALE_Y MTRANS_Y] * [MSKEW_Y 1 0] 
[MPERSP_0 MPERSP_1 MPERSP_2]  [0 0 1]
```

then how Matrix.preRotate(float degrees) (or postRotate(float degrees) or setRotate(float degrees)) works in this Mathematical form?????

Comment: Exactly like this, just with a rotation matrix.

Comment: And what is a rotation matix(In Mathematical Form)?????

Comment: [Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions). It wouldn't hurt to google something first if you don't know it.